# How many parallel threads i can run on my nvidia graphic card in cuda programming?

Tags: cuda

Operating System:   Windows 8.1 Single Language, 64-bit
DirectX version:    11.0
GPU processor:      GeForce 840M
Driver version:     353.06
Direct3D API version:   11.2
Direct3D feature level: 11_0
CUDA Cores:     384 
Core clock:     1029 MHz 
Memory data rate:   1800 MHz
Memory interface:   64-bit 
Memory bandwidth:   14.40 GB/s
Total available graphics memory:    4096 MB
Dedicated video memory: 2048 MB DDR3
System video memory:    0 MB
Shared system memory:   2048 MB
Video BIOS version: 82.08.14.00.64
IRQ:            Not used
Bus:            PCI Express x4 Gen2
Device Id:      10DE 1341 2281103C
Part Number:        2701 0000

Comment: it has 384 cores. Therefore, it can execute 384 threads concurrently, but if you looking for the maximum number of threads that can be scheduled per sm, refer table 12 of http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability

Comment: "How many threads does my GPU have" is not a meaningful question in its current wording.

Comment: I am sorry for my english and technical knowledge @buttiful buttefly but i am complete new to gpu coding and want to know how many parallel threads it can run. I generated 1,000,000 thread in my codebut i dont think it is running that many threads in parallel thats why i asked this question.

Comment: @warunapww i found my gpu have 3 SMM and every SMM can have 2048 threads so it can run 3*2048=6144 threads in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the CUDA Version used I think.

```
                Compute capability(version)            V1.0     V1.2     V2.x      V3.0-X.X
 Maximum number of resident threads per multiprocessor  768     1024    1536    2048
 Amount of local memory per thread                      16 KB           512 KB
 Maximum number of threads per block                    512             1024
```

If found this peace of Information on [CUDA - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA).
For more informations look under

> Version features and specifications

I Hope I could help :)

Comment: Thanks , it helps. I checked on wikipedia it says my gpu have 3 SMM and every SMM can have 2048 threads so it can run 3*2048=6144 threads in parallel.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help.